# How to print a variable's name in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatic way to get variable name in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623111/programmatic-way-to-get-variable-name-in-c)

I have checked some of the blogs before posting this here. I have tried the following snippet...

```
int a=21;

int main()
{
   cout<<#a<<a<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I am using g++ compiler on ubuntu 10.04. And I am getting the following error:

```
sample.cpp:17: error: stray ‘#’ in program.
```

Please suggest me how to print the variables name .

Comment: Why do you tag C if you're using `g++` and `cout` ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623111/programmatic-way-to-get-variable-name-in-c

Answer (score 14):

The `#` stringifying macro thing only works inside macros.

You could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define VNAME(x) #x
#define VDUMP(x) std::cout << #x << " " << x << std::endl

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  std::cout << VNAME(i) << " " << i << std::endl;

  VDUMP(i);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin - But you can make the macro more complex.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin that's not quite the same: if you rename your variable to `j` and forget to update the `"i"` string, there would be no compile-time error; using `VNAME` macro on a *variable* ensures that the printed value stays "synchronized" with the compile-time name of the variable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight What if you renamed your variable to `j` and there was another variable called `i`? There'd be no compile time error, and it'd show the wrong name. The `VDUMP` macro that just got added is far better.

Comment: @jamesmclaughlin VDUMP suffers from the same problem as VNAME: in case you rename i to j but there is another variable called i, you'd see a correct but useless output (assuming that you wanted to see j, not i), so it is still wrong. my point was that a variable name is visible to the compiler, but the content of a string constant is not.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `VDUMP` provides safety that the variable you're printing matches the label. Printing the _wrong_ variable is a different problem entirely (and an unavoidable one).

Answer (score 0):

The `#` is for if you are writing a macro.

If your `cout` line were a macro, it would work the way you expect.

If you're not in a macro, you just type `"a"`.