# A standard way for getting variable name at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, compile-time

Is there some way in C++11 or higher to achieve a similar behavior to:

```
int some_int;
std::string x=variable_name<some_int>::value; //Theoretical code 
std::cout << x;
```

Result should be:

> some_int

If not, is there a compiler specific way to do it? I am targeting MSVS.

Comment: Can you provide the real use case for the sought functionality? In this example you could simply write `std::string x = "some_int";`

Comment: If you don't mind about macro, you can use [preprocessor's stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification)

Comment: You could use a makro `#define NAME(VAR) #VAR`. Also works if everything else, e.g  `NAME(123) -> "123"`

Comment: @wasthishelpful nice option.. I did not know it is exist.. thanks

Comment: @Leon... Yes I am writing a logger for cv::Mat object.. I want to pass only the cv::Mat variable to the logging method and want it to automatically save it on the disk using its variable name

Comment: @Leon One use case I can think of is using it to throw `std::invalid_argument` with a function parameter name in a future-proof manner. (If the parameter name changes later down the line, you will get a compiler error, unless you also change the name, passed to exception constructor. With `std::string` you don't get any errors, if you forget to change the parameter name string.) So, basically, the same use case as for [C#'s `nameof` operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695900/what-is-the-purpose-of-nameof).

Comment: You ask for variable name but call your hypothetical solution `type_name`. Which is it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry edited

Comment: See, I don't really get the utility of this. If you already have to write `variable_name<some_int>::value`, why don't you just write `"some_int"` and be done with it? I suppose you get compile-time checks against typos, but otherwise...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit as I commented above " I am writing a logger for cv::Mat object.. I want to pass only the cv::Mat variable to the logging method and want it to automatically save it on the disk using its variable name" 
I want to make the logger interface cleaner while I do not care too much what is inside it

Comment: @iammilind Is there any chance we could reopen either this question, or [How to print a variable's name in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444988/how-to-print-a-variables-name-in-c)? I mean, the latter was closed as a duplicate of "Programmatic way to get variable name in C?", even though (at least IMHO) there may be a C++-specific way to better address this problem.

Comment: @TerraPass, OK I have reopened the Q, as it's not the exact duplicate of [What are the applications of the ## preprocessor operator and gotchas to consider?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/216875/514235), but it's the exact duplicate of [How to print a variable's name in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444988/how-to-print-a-variables-name-in-c). You may post the solution and let the others or **moderator** take the decision of closing this Q.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: But you already have to write the variable name in order to reference the variable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See my answer. We *do* have to write the variable name, but if we implement the stringification macro in a certain way, compiler will be able to whack us across the fingers with a compiler error, if we mistype/forget to change the variable's name. This is not the case if we simply use a string literal.

Comment: @TerraPass: As I alluded to earlier, that seems like a fringe benefit for the effort required, but I can see it I guess. The other problem is that an object may have multiple names so from a purist perspective this doesn't really make sense anyway.

Comment: @terra Parameter names at interface and in body of function are unrelated.  So not future proofed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You ask:

> Is there some way in C++11 or higher to achieve a similar behavior to:
>
> ```
> int some_int;
> std::string x=type_name<some_int>::value; //Theoretical code 
> std::cout << x;
> ```
>
> Result should be:
>
> > some_int

Yes, you can just use the preprocessor's *stringizing operator* `#`:

```
#include <iostream>

#define NAME_OF( v ) #v

using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    int some_int;
     //std::string x=type_name<some_int>::value; //Theoretical code 
    auto x = NAME_OF( some_int );
    (void) some_int;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

If you're asking for something different, then please post a new question since this one has now been answered (amending the question would invalidate this answer).

---

As an example real world **usage**, here's macro to pass a variable and its name to a test function:

```
#define TEST( v ) test( v, #v )
```

---

If you want a **compile time check** that the name in question is a variable or type name, then you can simply apply `sizeof`, e.g. in a comma expression:

```
#define NAME_OF( v ) (sizeof(v), #v)
```

The difference between having `sizeof` or not, is whether this is guaranteed to be done purely at compile time, versus possibly generating code to also do something at run time.

To avoid a possible warning you can add a pseudo-cast to `void`:

```
#define NAME_OF( v ) ((void) sizeof(v), #v)
```

And to make this work also for a function name you can add a `typeid`:

```
#define NAME_OF( name ) ((void) sizeof(typeid(name)), #name)
```

Complete example:

```
#include <typeinfo>

#define NAME_OF( name ) ((void) sizeof(typeid(name)), #name)

void foo() {}

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    int some_int;
    (void) some_int;
     //std::string x=type_name<some_int>::value; //Theoretical code 
    auto v = NAME_OF( some_int );
    auto t = NAME_OF( int );
    auto f = NAME_OF( foo );
    #ifdef TEST_CHECKING
        (void) NAME_OF( not_defined );
    #endif
    cout << v << ' ' << t << ' ' << f << endl;
}
```

The checking is not 100% perfect, though, because it's still possible to pass a function invocation to the `NAME_OF` macro.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Your comment indicates that this is not an answer. On the contrary, it does exactly what's asked for. A comment about the impracticality of the goal should go *on the question*, not on each answer.

Comment: Maybe a compile time check of the argument for `NAME_OF` would be useful; something like `#define NAME_OF( v ) ((void)v, #v)`?

Comment: @Niall: Yes, I considered that, but didn't do it because it wouldn't work with type names then. However that way of thinking (that I did) is wrong; there's no need to automate everything. The programmer certainly knows whether the code is intended to deal with variable or type name, and can express this.

Answer (score 10):

As others have pointed out, you can indeed use a macro to "stringify" the variable name. However, instead of simply defining it as `#define NAMEOF(variable) #variable`, you can use the following definition:

```
#define NAMEOF(variable) ((decltype(&variable))nullptr, #variable)
```

As you can see, it uses a comma operator. The left part of this expression does nothing but performs a (pointless) conversion from `nullptr` to a pointer to `variable`'s type, the result of which gets immediately discarded. The right part simply returns the stringified variable's name.

**Why is this better than simply using `#variable` in the macro?**

Thanks to the `decltype()` operator, the whole thing will only compile if you pass a variable of some sort and not some arbitrary string or a literal to `NAMEOF` macro. Consider the following example:

```
double value = 523231231312.0095;

cout<< NAMEOF(value) << endl;    // value

cout<< NAMEOF(value1) << endl;   // Compiler error: 'value1' was not declared in this scope

cout<< NAMEOF(42) << endl;       // Compiler error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
```

Because of this, if during future refactoring you modify the name of `value` variable, you won't forget to also modify places, where you use its name, since compiler will scream at you, until you also fix every usage of `NAMEOF` for this variable.

*Tested on MinGW-W64 (gcc v5.2.0)*

---

In the comments, `@iammilind` and `@Niall` have suggested two other ways to define this macro, which don't rely on C++11-specific `decltype()` operator:

```
#define NAMEOF(variable) ((void*)&variable, #variable)
```

...or...

```
// Unlike other definitions, this one, suggested by @Niall,
// won't get broken even if unary & operator for variable's type
// gets overloaded in an incompatible manner.
#define NAMEOF(variable) ((void)variable, #variable)

// On the other hand, it accepts literals as parameters for NAMEOF,
// though this might be desired behaviour, depending on your requirements.
NAMEOF(42);    // 42
```

---

Using such a macro with `@Leon`'s suggestion, based on your comments, we get:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T var, const char* varname)
{
    std::cout << varname << "=" << var << std::endl;
}

#define FOO(var) foo(var, NAMEOF(var))

int someVariable = 5;

FOO(someVariable);           // someVariable = 5

FOO(nonExistingVariable);    // compiler error!
```

Comment: Simple `(void*)&v` is enough, if the C++11 is not in the reach. Anyways, good observation.

Comment: If the address-of operator is overloaded, a `(void)v` would be enough/better.

Comment: @Niall This breaks the case where we pass a literal: `NAMEOF(42)` no longer leads to a compiler error.

Comment: Doesn't break anything - it just prints the "name" of the literal as "42" - doesn't sound wrong. The OP didn't have anything on that not being a valid use case anyway; either way, it's a trade-off.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I've added them to the answer.

Comment: @Yakk Then using `(void)variable`, as Niall suggested, would be the most reliable approach, correct?

Answer (score 5):

As follows from the [**comments**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696440/a-standard-way-for-getting-variable-name-at-compile-time/38696716#comment64771433_38696440), you need it for passing into a function both the value of the variable and its name. This must be done with the help of a macro:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void foo(T var, const char* varname)
{
    std::cout << varname << "=" << var << std::endl;
}

#define FOO(var) foo(var, #var)

int main()
{
    int i = 123;
    double d = 45.67;
    std::string s = "qwerty";

    FOO(i);
    FOO(d);
    FOO(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
i=123
d=45.67
s=qwerty
```

Comment: Should be `T&` not `T`

Comment: `T&` has the interesting property that `FOO` will only work on lvalues, which is probably what we want here. Otherwise, you can do `FOO(2 + 2)`, which might not be what we want