# How to assign values to the data elements of a structure

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a structure

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int intValue1;
    float floatValue2;
    std::string stringValue3;
} Structure;
```

Now based on the value input of two strings, I want to assign values to the data elements of the structure:

```
std::string varName = "intValue1";
std::string varValue = "5";
```

So based on the two strings the "intValue1" should get a value of 5

```
Structure.intValue1 = (int)varValue;
```

Is it possible to write a function which would automatically assign values to the structure based on the input strings, e.g.:

```
 void SetData( std::string varName , std::string varValue );
```

Comment: `Structure.intValue1 = std::stoi(varValue);` will probably work better.

Comment: This *looks* like you want to convert a string to a variable name. That's not currently possible in c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, using [stringizing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696440/a-standard-way-for-getting-variable-name-at-compile-time) . Here is a minimalistic example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#define NAME_OF( v ) #v

struct MyStruct
{
    int intValue1;
    float floatValue2;
    std::string stringValue3;
} Structure;


int main()
{
  MyStruct A;

  std::string varName = "intValue1";
  std::string varValue = "5";

  auto var_name = NAME_OF(A.intValue1);

  if (varName.compare(var_name) != 0) {
    A.intValue1 = std::stoi(varValue);
  }
  std::cout << A.intValue1 << " " << varValue << std::endl;
}
```

Hope this helps!