# Printing the name of a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, printf

Is it possible to print the struct name?

say i have a struct:

```
typedef struct someName{
uint16_t  value;
uint16_t  field;
} someName_t;

someName_t test;

printf("%" PRIu16 "\n", test;
printf("%" PRIu16 "\n", test.value);
```

Printing test.value is oke. Printing test gives me warning..
Is this the right way to print the name of the struct, is it even possible in C?

First of all PRIu16 is something i found on stackoverflow which was the right way to print uint16_t..

I want to print the name someName_t.

Comment: I... what? Maybe you should provide us with sample output you want...?

Comment: You want to first printf to print `test`?

Comment: tell me first what you want by printing name of struct? you defined it..you give name it So what is issue?

Comment: In C++, its possible with [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), AFAIK not possible in C

Comment: I know c. But I didn't see any printf statement like above. can any one explain? `"%" PRIu16 "\n"`

Comment: Do you mean the name of the struct `someName` or the variable (expression) `test` you are working with?

Comment: `"%" PRIu16` prints an `uint16_t`. `printf` natively work with C types, e.g. `%ld` means print a `long`. `uint16_t` on the other hand can differ between compilers, it can be a `short` in some environments and `int` in others. `PRIu16` simply expands to a suitable letter for `printf` to use. `"\n"` print a new line.

Comment: @P0W If you are referring to `std::type_info::name`, that is rarely an helpful name and it's implementation defined.

Comment: Printing the names of variables doesn't make sense. There exist no variable names in the executable. If you want this for debugging purposes, simply `printf("test")`.

Comment: @P0W: It can be done in the preprocessor.

Comment: It can be done and it makes sense, but it's complex and error prone. I do it in C++ through preprocessor macros and it enables runtime checks and other stuff, but it would be more complex without at least function overloading.

I upvoted the question because I believe having the name of the struct is very useful and I apply the concept myself, just never had to do it in C but it can be done similarly as what @staticx proposed. The difference would be that the struct has to be declared through macros, and instances of it must be initialized to set the name pointer (or other metadata you like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to declare your structures, first of all you need some macros defined as follows:

```
   #define BEGIN_NAMED_STRUCT(structName)   \
   typedef struct structName                \
   {                                        \
       const char* __name;

   #define END_NAMED_STRUCT(structName) \
   } structName##_t;                    \
   init_##structName( structName* s );

   #define INIT_NAMED_STRUCT_TYPE( structName )         \
   static const char* structName##__name = #structName;   \
   void init_##structName( structName* s )              \
   {                                                    \
       s->__name = structName##__name;                      \
   }
```

Then in your .h or wherever your declaration should be, you declare your struct like this:

```
   BEGIN_NAMED_STRUCT(someName)   
      uint16_t  value;
      uint16_t  field;
   END_NAMED_STRUCT(someName);
```

And in your .c you have to initialize the metadata which is done like this:

```
   INIT_NAMED_STRUCT_TYPE( someName );
```

Then you can do the following in your program and all your structures declared like that will have the "__name" member which you can access whenever you want:

```
   int main()
   {
       someName_t mySomeInstance;
       init_someName( &mySomeInstance );
       printf( mySomeInstance->__name );
       return 0;
   }
```

But this is very error prone unless you develop a large set of functions to provide safety due to the metrics of the metadata added to the struct and other issues. In C++ you can do something similar but taking advantage of function overloading and templates which makes this technique to make more sense than in C.

Btw I didn't test this particular code, I wrote it in a rush so it may not work as expected :)

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like this (it will print `test = 0`):

```
#define DUMP(varname) fprintf(stderr, "%s = %x", #varname, varname);

typedef struct someName 
{
   int  value;
   int  field;
} someName_t;

someName_t test;

// pseudocode
int main()
{
   DUMP(test);
}
```

Running here: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1623148/2591612

Comment: @pmg: I don't take credit for it, but it solves the OP's problem I think

Answer (score 2):

You could use the stringize operator and define a print function for the variable name together with the variable declaration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* This declares a variable name together with a function print_name */
#define declarePrintable(type, name) int print_##name() { return printf("%s", #name); } struct type name

struct someType
{
    int i;
};

declarePrintable(someType, someName);

int main()
{
    someName.i = 3; 
    print_someName(); 
    printf(".i is %d ", someName.i );
}
```

Comment: `error: stray ‘#’ in program`. You can only do this with a __macro parameter__, not with a macro name.

Comment: hmh hm hm :-) never post untested code... and now I did it twice... thx

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

Object names only exist in source form. After the program is compiled, no more object names exist.

But you can, of course, print a string

```
printf("%s\n", "test");
```

<sup>As [staticx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2591612/staticx) suggests you can use the preprocessor to create a string based on the object name and print that string.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

The object code created by compiling any C code will contain no literal strings that contain the names of any variables or variable types, except perhaps if there is debugging info created in the compiled code, or if you deliberately create such literal strings in your source code. Any literal strings you embed will require maintenance to keep in sync with refactored code or new variables. 
*Ergo*, you cannot print those variable names. Even if there is a debug option built into the object code, the literal strings are still not available to the code itself; only the debugger knows how to use them. You seem to want some kind of automatic way of seeing the names of variables at runtime. Perhaps you are better served by using a debugger, or explaining what you are really trying to do.