# Getting the name of a class in C++

Tags: c++, classname

In my `print` method, I want to print the name of my Team class ("Bar").
Is there a way to get the name of a class without sending it as an argument?
I want to build inside the ostream cout << operator something like
"Team name : **function that gets the name ("Bar" in this case) **"

```
int main ()
{
    cout << "hello"<<endl;
    Team Bar;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Bar.addPlayer();
    }

    cout << Bar; //here I want to print the name of the Team ("Bar") without having a string Bar as a parameter

    Bar.manage();
    cout << Bar;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In fact, do you want to print the variable name? Please include also the definition of the Team class. `Bar` is just an instance of the class, aka a variable. The answer to your question may lay [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1623111/2436175).

Comment: Hmm, weird, I listed two duplicates in the close vote, but only one appeared when the question got closed. Anyway, the second one was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649278/how-can-i-get-the-class-name-from-a-c-object

Comment: How can you vote for _two_ duplicates, @Singer?

Comment: @Lightness, well, I'm sure I have tried listing the URLs separated by a comma before, and it seemed to work.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Really? I must try that! (Seems unlikely, though...)

Comment: @Lightness, well, it's also possible that my memory fails me and it had never worked like that...

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Could be ;)

Answer (score 0):

No. This has nothing to do with classes: you cannot print, at runtime, the name of *any* variable. Those names no longer exist after your code is compiled.

Comment: inb4 "yes they do as debug symbols" shush irrelevant and not helpful here

Comment: There are programmatic ways, though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623111/programmatic-way-to-get-variable-name-in-c