# variable name, function arguments at run time in C

Tags: c, linux, gdb, bfd, dladdr

Is it possible to know a function arguments and variables' name types at runtime in C program ? For example, if I have a function:

```
int abc(int x, float y , somestruct z ){
    char a;
    int b ;
}
```

Can I know inside this function `abc()`, what are the names of arguments and variables *i.e.* in this case its `x`, `y`, `z`, `a`, `b` and they are of type `int`, `float`, `somestruct`, `char`, `int`.

Say if there is another function:

```
float some_func(specialstruct my_struct, int index){

}
```

I should know that arguments name are `my_struct`, `index` and types are `specialstruct`, `int`.

I need this info at runtime ?

I have access to base pointer and return address , can I get required info using above pointer.

I was able to extract function name using return address and `dladdr()` function.

I see `GDB` does this, so it should be possible to extract this info?

Comment: Why do you need those names at runtime? What could you do with them?

Comment: C is a compiled language. Once the program has been compiled (or in other words once it has been transformed into machine code) all variable names, function names etc. are gone. So the answer is: No. On the other hand GDB knows about variable and function names, because the program has been compiled with special options, but this is useful for debugging only.

Comment: `gdb` use debugging information that are generated by the compiler. See http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information/

Comment: @MichaelWalz: If compiled or not is not the problem. A compiled language can also "refelcect" attributes back to the code itself. Reflection was part of c++17 but is removed as I know. Other languages have this feature.

Comment: @Klaus correct, but there is no reflection what so ever in C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatic way to get variable name in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623111/programmatic-way-to-get-variable-name-in-c)

Comment: No. Types aren't (in general) part of the runtime execution of the program. Types only exist in the language, i.e. in the thing that *describes* the program. A C program does not generally know its own description (unless you explicitly make it so).

Comment: @Mat ,Lets say assert condition is true but i dont want to stop execution, so i want to dump my call stack along with argument and variable name along with values.

Comment: Edit that into your question (should have been there from the start). There are no portable ways to get that. Accurate variable dump for optimized dump is prob. impossible.

Answer (score 2):

As others noted, reflection is not built into the C or C++ language.  There are a variety of ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353022/reflection-support-in-c)

However, Reflection is possible in C/C++ with a 3rd party library and debugging symbols in the executable or an external file.

The `dwarfdump` executable more or less does what you are hoping for.  With the DWARF information details on function, variables, types, etc are available.   In a similar fashion, the libdwarfdump functionality could be used by a process to inspect itself.

Here is a simple manual example:

```
typedef struct somestruct 
{
   int i;
   int j;
} somestruct ;

int abc(int x, float y , struct somestruct z ){
    char a;
    int b ;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

   struct somestruct z;
   abc(1,1.0f,z);
   return 0;
}
```

and the partial output from dwarfdump

```
< 1><0x00000055>    DW_TAG_subprogram
                      DW_AT_external              yes(1)
                      DW_AT_name                  "abc"
                      DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /tmp/dwarf.c
                      DW_AT_decl_line             0x00000009
                      DW_AT_prototyped            yes(1)
                      DW_AT_type                  <0x0000004e>
                      DW_AT_low_pc                0x004004ed
                      DW_AT_high_pc               <offset-from-lowpc>18
                      DW_AT_frame_base            len 0x0001: 9c: DW_OP_call_frame_cfa
                      DW_AT_GNU_all_call_sites    yes(1)
                      DW_AT_sibling               <0x000000ad>
< 2><0x00000076>      DW_TAG_formal_parameter
                        DW_AT_name                  "x"
                        DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /tmp/dwarf.c
                        DW_AT_decl_line             0x00000009
                        DW_AT_type                  <0x0000004e>
                        DW_AT_location              len 0x0002: 916c: DW_OP_fbreg -20
< 2><0x00000082>      DW_TAG_formal_parameter
                        DW_AT_name                  "y"
                        DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /tmp/dwarf.c
                        DW_AT_decl_line             0x00000009
                        DW_AT_type                  <0x000000ad>
                        DW_AT_location              len 0x0002: 9168: DW_OP_fbreg -24
< 2><0x0000008e>      DW_TAG_formal_parameter
                        DW_AT_name                  "z"
                        DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /tmp/dwarf.c
                        DW_AT_decl_line             0x00000009
                        DW_AT_type                  <0x0000002d>
                        DW_AT_location              len 0x0002: 9160:        DW_OP_fbreg -32
```

With careful study, we can see the fragment defines the function 'abc' with arguements x, y and z.

The type of parameter x is an indirection to a type table with key 0x4e.

Looking elsewhere in the output, we can see the definition for type 0x4e.  Type 0x2d is the somestruct which ties back to parameter z.

```
< 1><0x0000002d>    DW_TAG_structure_type
                      DW_AT_name                  "somestruct"
                      DW_AT_byte_size             0x00000008
                      DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /tmp/dwarf.c
                      DW_AT_decl_line             0x00000003
                      DW_AT_sibling               <0x0000004e>

< 1><0x0000004e>    DW_TAG_base_type
                      DW_AT_byte_size             0x00000004
                      DW_AT_encoding              DW_ATE_signed
                      DW_AT_name                  "int"
```

The combination of ptrace, ELF, DWARF and the /proc filesystem allow gdb to read static and dynamic information for a process. Another process could use similar functionality to create Reflection functionality.

I have used variants of this strategy to create custom debuggers and memory leak detectors.  I have never seen this strategy used for business logic however.

Answer (score 1):

There is no kind of reflection or similar things in C. If you want such facility - you should design some utilities, macros for this purpose and use special coding rules to achieve desired effect. But IMO - it won't be a readable and understandable C code.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a native way to do this in C. In other languages, what you'd be looking for would be reflection. You can cheese it with macros and some tricks, but on a basic principle, you need to know variable names and arguments at compile time.

Comment: @Mat Apparently, I did a brainfart there. I was referring to the arguments the _program_ is launched with. Correcting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited way of introspection provided by shared library functions `dlsym` and `dladdr` providing a name-to-address and vice versa translation. That is, however, not part of the C language, but rather a function supplied by the OS dynamic loader. You can, however, not deduct, for example, whether that symbol you found is a variable or function.

`backtrace` et al make up a GNU extension to the standard that allows to analyze the call stack of a function (call history). If there are symbols (function names) still present in the binary, `backtrace_symbols` will allow you to retrieve them.

The `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` predefined macros provide a way to dump where you are as well and can be the basis of some very useful macros for tracing.

**And that's it**. C does not provide any more introspection than that. Parameter names and types are gone in the binary, function signatures are gone and function result types as well.